# How can I show columns number in Notepad++?

Tags: text, ide, editor, notepad++, text-editor

in **Notepad++** can I show also the **columns number** (where a column is a single written character) as I do for the rows number?

Tnx

Comment: Well you have first to define what do you consider a column in n++

Comment: @apomene a column for me is a single character

Comment: Checkout this discussion: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/db5bc3ed

Answer (score 17):

[image]

Notepad++ already has the required feature. There's no need for any extension or plugin. Look for the information presented in the bar at the bottom of Notepad++ window.

The image shows my cursor is at Line:1 and Col:70

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ColumnTools plugin. It has a ruler and a vertical bar option to aid working on the columns.

Through the plugins menu or https://github.com/VinsWorldcom/nppColumnTools

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin called *[TextFX](http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2014/10/15/edit-columns-in-notepad-with-textfx-plugin/)* .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called `TextFX`.

And before making a column :

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8 -- insert this 
data1|data2|data3|data4
```

then using `textFX` to make a column.

Answer (score 0):

Beware special characters : col and pos may differ.
[3 screenshots of NotePad++, showing the difference between Col and Pos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KncZh.png)